# Error running npm install npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

Tags: node.js, docker

doing a docker course and i'm receiving this error now, i've been trying to figure it out for an hour but still haven't been able to. Looking for an explanation as to why this is happening. Thanks!

```
    abdullahyasinahmad@Abdullahs-MBP visits % docker build .
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
    Step 1/6 : FROM node:alpine
     ---> 66f36cfbf155
    Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/app
     ---> Using cache
     ---> c75d13f7a8d9
    Step 3/6 : COPY package.json .
     ---> Using cache
     ---> a0ad07b89732
    Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
     ---> Running in ec0f65f48bca
    npm notice 
    npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.8 -> 7.0.11
    npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.11>
    npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.11` to update!
    npm notice 
    npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR! path /usr/app/package.json
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing empty string
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-17T03_15_25_297Z-debug.log
    The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

```
    const express = require('express');
    const redis = require('redis');

    const app = express();
    const client = redis.createClient();
    client.set('visits', 0)

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
        res.send('Number of visits is ' + visits);
        client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
      });
    });

    app.listen(8081, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 8081');
    });
```

'''

PACKAGE JSON FILE

```
      {
          "dependencies": {
            "express": "*",
            "redis": "2.8.0"
          },
          "scripts": {
            "start": "node index.js"
          }
        }
```

'''

Console Log

```
    Nov 16 22:23:29 Abdullahs-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]          
   (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.docker-credenti.55164): Failed to bootstrap path: path=       /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain, error = 2: No such file or 
    directory
```

Comment: The error: "npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing empty string" implies that package.json file is not formatted properly. Search for an online JSON parser to properly format it and try again.

Comment: Share your json file

Comment: You may want to try npm cache clean and retry the install to see that helps

Comment: @NirAlfasi Thanks for that, so I did that and it worked, but i don't see anything different.. What would cause that to occur? the parser didn't add any new code everything is identical?

Comment: Sounds like you had spaces at the end of the file or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `node:14`. Works for me!:

```
docker run -it node:14  npm install -g npm@7.0.12
```